# Efficient one-liner in Julia to calculate "running" sums?

Tags: julia

Is there an efficient way to do the following in Julia in one line of code?

```
foldl((prev, x)-> [prev; prev[end] + x] , 0, block_lengths)
```

For example, for

```
block_lengths = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

the desired output is

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11]
```

(I presume that the way I used `foldl` above is inefficient, because I'm concatenating a vector and an integer at each iteration.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `cumsum`:

```
julia> block_lengths = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3];

julia> cumsum(block_lengths)
5-element Array{Int32,1}:
  2
  4
  6
  8
 11

julia> [0; cumsum(block_lengths)]
6-element Array{Int32,1}:
  0
  2
  4
  6
  8
 11
```

which should be O(N).